# Installing windows server standard 2008 32bit in IBM System X-3620

Tags: windows-server-2008, ibm, ibm-xseries

Can anyone explain me how to install windows server standard 2008 32bit with sata/sas 6gb/s hdd in IBM System X-3620. During the installation, the os cannot detect the drive. I had even tried with IBM server guide utility but 2008 standard edition is not in the os list. There is no instruction in IBM site also for installing windows server standard 2008 in X-3620. My sas is 44W2239. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7):

When it asks where you want to install and there's no drives listed, there's a button that says "Load Driver..."

[image]

Click it and load the storage driver for your system (you might need to put them onto a USB stick or swap DVDs).

Answer (score 2):

The [IBM ServerGuide CD](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=SERV-GUIDE) is the optimal method of installing Windows on IBM servers. Have you used the latest version?

It will:

- set up RAID
- set the time/etc
- pre-stage the Windows install with all necessary drivers
- start the Windows install

This is the recommended approach and will make your job dead simple.

*(yes, I am an IBM VAR)*